# Previouse git commits are missing

Tags: git, gitlab, gitignore, git-commit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5muQ.png)
My previous 90+ commits  are not showing in my branch neither in other :(.

I've only clue that the commit are gone after solving the git error **failed to resolve HEAd as valid ref**, or may be it is because of pushing the codes forcefully.

**STEP-1**

Added `.gitignore` File in dir with some additional rules to ignore irrelevant dirs/files.

**STEP-2**

```
git add .
git commit -m "msg"
git push origin dev_branch -f
```

This are the most recent command for I've executed in my terminal.
Thanks in advance

Comment: this is why you don't force push

Comment: Thankfully the commits are not gone (yet). You could use the reflog to find the "missing" commits, and then create branches which point to them. That will stop them being garbage collected.

Comment: @mousetail Where does this rule come from? Force push is perfectly fine as a tool. The problem here is due to using git without understanding its basic usage and concepts.

Comment: I dislike force pushing and the whole workflow of rebasing/squashing in general, since it's so very easy to make mistakes like this.

Comment: It would help a lot if you described the exact sequence of commands that led to this problem (see [ask] and [mre]). Of course, it's likely that you don't *know* this sequence. In general though the error message you got doesn't happen from normal everyday Git usage *unless* you put your repository in a place where it can be corrupted, e.g., in a cloud-synchronized folder (Dropbox, iCloud, etc).

Comment: Hii @torek,
I've edited my question to explain the last executed command before I started getting this error. Can you please help me to resolve this issue?


Also I've tried `git reflog`. it return only few commits.

Comment: Well, the `git push origin dev_branch -f` (force push) tells the receiving Git repository: "Throw away all the commits except the ones I'm telling you to keep now", so that could be a problem. This would not produce `failed to resolve HEAD as a valid ref` though. I also see that you've used both [tag:github] and [tag:gitlab] tags; these are different hosting companies and you should use only the one corresponding to whatever hosting site you're actually using. GitHub keep every commit even if you tell them to throw some away, so if you're on GitHub, contact their support.

Answer (score 1):

1. `git reflog`.
2. If you find the most recent commit that are missing then `git checkout -b phew_branch <commit_sha_of_the_most_recent_commit_that_was_lost>.`

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried running `git reflog` but it is not working for me. Is there any thing else to do to get back my lost commits.

Comment: What does it mean when you say it is not working for you?

Comment: It means it is showing the commit list of after force merger as I asked in my Question (Added image for clarification).

Comment: Where is the picture from? Is it really output of  'git reflog'?

Comment: The Above picture is from Git-Lab console and the terminal output is also the same for `git reflog`